# Rename Multiple files with in Dos batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I wish to rename all files inside the folder  *.txt,
so the result will be
"1.txt", "2.txt" and "3.txt", ....

How can I do so?

Comment: Does it matter if the new name bears any relationship to the old name? e.g. AAA.txt -> 1.txt, BBB.txt -> 2.txt

Comment: No, I want to rename it with serial e.g. cat.txt, dog.txt, rat.txt -> 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and so on

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following may accomplish what you are looking for.  It uses a `for` loop to iterate through the text files and makes a "call" to another bit of the batch file to do the rename and increment of a variable.

**Edit** Change math operation to cleaner solution suggested by Andriy.

```
@echo off
set i=1
for %%f in (*.txt) do call :renameit "%%f"
goto done

:renameit
ren %1 %i%.txt
set /A i+=1

:done
```

Comment: There are two problems, Only one file has been renamed, and if the file names contain spaces, the batch can't rename any file

Comment: @JustMe:  I edited the response and put quotes around the `%%f` to handle the file names with spaces.  It is not clear, though, why only one file would be processed.  It may well be due to a different DOS version.

Comment: +1. By the way, `SET /A i=i+1` or even `SET /A i+=1` would do just as well.

Comment: @Andriy:  Thanks.  That's cleaner; I made that change.  I didn't realize that worked (some day I will learn to read documentation ... maybe).

Comment: @MarkWilkins, hey this works great but how do you keep the original name? my original file name is `20160824.txt` it renames them all to thru `1.txt ..4.txt`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Renaming was the entire point.  If you don't want them renamed, then ... well don't don't do anything and you will still have the original name.  Or if you want both, copy them instead of rename (although I am not sure what the for command does if you are adding .txt files while looping; you would need to test).

Answer (score 1):

First make a directory listing:

```
dir /b *.txt > myfile.cmd
```

Then start up UltraEdit (http://www.ultraedit.com/) and open the file.

Then go into column mode, select all lines, and:

- insert "RENAME " in the beginning of every line
- insert ".TXT" at the end of every line (be sure to put it far enough right in case you have very long lines)
- insert a number (see Column / Insert Number in the menu) right before .TXT

Answer (score 1):

I wish to rename all files inside the folder *.txt, so the result will be "1.txt", "2.txt" and "3.txt", ....

How can I do so?

```
::Setup the stage...
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET folder=C:\This\Is\The\Folder
SET count=1

::Action
CD "%folder%"
FOR %%F IN ("*.txt") DO (
 MOVE "%%F" "!count!.txt"
 SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Shorthand

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
FOR %%F IN (C:\Path\To\File\*.txt) DO MOVE "%%~fF" "%%~dpF!count!.txt" & SET /a count=!count!+1
ENDLOCAL
```

So if your folder contained cat.txt, dog.txt, bird.txt, ninjaturtle.txt, it will output 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt.