# batch script to edit file names

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

My file names pattern is **a_AA-A.txt** or **a_11-1.txt**. I need to remove "**a_**" from the file name.

Is it possible to edit / remove "**a_**" from file name through batch commands.

I am using windows 7

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to simply remove the first two characters

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%A in ('dir /b a_*.txt') do (
    set old_filename=%%~A
    set new_filename=!old_filename:~2!
    rename !old_filename! !new_filename!
)
```

If you want to remove the characters a_

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%A in ('dir /b a_*.txt') do (
    set old_filename=%%~A
    set new_filename=!old_filename:a_=!
    rename !old_filename! !new_filename!
)
```

Comment: can he do ('dir /b a_*.txt') to be sure?

Comment: That's actually a better solution; now it ignores any text files in the directory that may have already had the script run on them. I've edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

not sure you can do this with batch... but you can do it with vbscript for sure...

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/81e7f64b-aa01-4087-b245-41f8a2972675/rename-a-file-in-vbscript?forum=ITCG

and you can call it from your batchjob

Comment: or take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359587/rename-multiple-files-with-in-dos-batch-file