# renaming many gifs in folder

Tags: rename, bulk, file-listing

I have a lot of files that have random generated names like `notqr64SC51ruz6zso3_250.gif` and I would like to rename them to simply `1.gif`, `2.gif` etc.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple UNIX shell script:

```
N=1; for i in `ls *.gif` ; do mv $i $N.gif ; N=$((N+1)); done
```

If you need padding:

```
N=1
for i in *.gif; do
  printf -v new "%06d.gif" ${N}
  mv -- "$i" "$new"
  N=$((N+1));
done
```

---

Under Windows you can use a (similar) batch file:

[Rename Multiple files with in Dos batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359587/rename-multiple-files-with-in-dos-batch-file)

---

If you can use Python:

```
import glob
import os

files = glob.glob("/path/to/folder/*.gif")    

n = 0
for fn in files:
    os.rename(fn, str(n).zfill(6) + '.gif')
    n += 1
```